# Touch Event in blackberry

Tags: blackberry, touch-event

I have created a VerticalFieldmanager optFieldManager
in which i have added some CustomButtons
Then i want to invoke the button's functionality using touch event method
i tried this using the TouchEvent() method
For this i do fetch the index of optFieldManager which gives the index value as 0
which confirms that the field is present
But then i again ask for the field inside the manager which returns -1 value which means there is no field added to Manager ... which isn't true
I debugged the code and found that the clicked postions are correctly returned

```
int index1=optionVertFldMgr.getFieldAtLocation(message.getX(1), message.getY(1));
```

but the index1 value comes as -1 which is wrong

what's the problem

I have added the snippet of code below

```
protected boolean touchEvent(TouchEvent message) {

            switch(message.getEvent())
            {

            case TouchEvent.CLICK:
            {
                int index=getFieldAtLocation(message.getX(1), message.getY(1));
                //int index1=optionVertFldMgr.getFieldAtLocation(message.getX(1), message.getY(1));
                if(index!=-1)
                {
                    Field field=getField(index);
                    if(field.equals(optionVertFldMgr))  
                    {

                        int index1=optionVertFldMgr.getFieldAtLocation(message.getX(1), message.getY(1));
                        System.out.println("HELOOOOOOO"+((VerticalFieldManager) field).getFieldAtLocation(message.getX(1), message.getY(1)));
                        //int index1=optionVertFldMgr.getFieldWithFocusIndex();
                        if(index1>-1)
                        {
                            Field fld=optionVertFldMgr.getField(index1);
                            if(fld.equals(m_agendaBtn))
                            {
                                fld.setFocus();
                                return true;
                            }else if(fld.equals(m_eventFeedBackBtn))
                            {
                                fld.setFocus();
                                UiApplication.getUiApplication().pushScreen(new EventFeedbackScreen());
                                return true;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            }
            return false;
            }
```

Comment: http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/Touch-event-is-working-outside-the-buttons/m-p/1662871#M196234

Comment: Go through the same way and try it..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always override [Field.navigationClick](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/5.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/ui/Field.html#navigationClick%28int,%20int%29) on each button, or even override once in the screen and manage from there all events from every field:

```
    public boolean navigationClick(int status, int time){
        Field f = getLeafFieldWithFocus();
        if(f == button1){
            //do something 1
            return true;    
        } else if(field == button2){
            //do something 2
            return true;
        }
        //more fields
        return false;   
    }
```

This approach works both for touchscreens and trackpad.